# Jquery Accordion Closes during mvc.Pagelist next page event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-accordion, pagedlist

i have a jquery accordion, everything works fine, inside it is a mvc.pagedlist, what happens is when i hit the next button inside it, the page reloads and the accordion window will close.. i tried adding the following codes to make a workaround but i seem cant make it work..

Controller // get method

```
    if (page != null)
        {
            ViewBag.PanelToOpen = 0;
        }
```

View

```
@section Scripts {
    <script> 

        var searchInputs = $("#SearchCriteria1").find("input[type=text], select");
        var emptyFields = 0;

        searchInputs.each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                emptyFields++;
            }
        });

        if (emptyFields == searchInputs.length) {
            $("#SearchCriteria1").accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true
            });
        } else {
            $("#SearchCriteria1").accordion({
                //active: false,
                collapsible: true
            });
        }
    </script>

    @if (ViewBag.PanelToOpen == 0)
    {
        <script> 
            $("#SearchCriteria1").accordion({
                active: true,
                collapsible: true
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```

Comment: you should set active panel Index to activate option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that we should set [`.accordion("option", "active","activePanelIndex")` click link to see docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-option)

And Here is the **[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/9k57wo7z/)**
Your JavaScript should change like below

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var activePanelIndex = "@ViewBag.PanelToOpen",
                accordionContainer = $("#SearchCriteria1"),
                searchInputs = $(":text, select", accordionContainer),
                emptyFields = searchInputs.filter(function () { return !!$(this).val(); }).length;

            accordionContainer.accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true
            });

            if (!activePanelIndex || emptyFields != searchInputs.length) {
                accordionContainer.accordion("option", "active", Number(activePanelIndex) || 0);
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Can I know, What is the cause for down vote? I did one working-test-case with above code , tested and Posted, I'm glad if you add comments, don't down-vote without reason!

Comment: i wasnt the one who down voted. probably another person. i have yet to try this solution tho,i will upvote it to negate the downvote.

Comment: @anonymous1110 Thank you! I've added Fiddle example to answer. You can check the intended behavior by changing the index of panel from 0 to 2 in html(not in result) first textbox index#indexOfPanelToOpen value